# Xcode debug memory graph showing released object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, xcode8

I've been looking in the Xcode Memory Graph tool for a project and was noticing some odd behaviour. Hoping someone might be able to explain what's going on/if I need to worry.

I have a view controller that creates a couple of objects (which aren't doing much at the moment) When I dismiss the view controller sure enough they get released. But one (sometimes both) seem to hang around in the visual debugger:

[image]

Only two are ever being created, and both are being deinitialized, confirmed in my consol:

[image]

I think I'm correct in saying, I'm not responsible for any of those objects referencing that `User` object in the image above, so is this a bug, or just something I don't need to worry about?

Comment: still having this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what is happening to you, but this has happened to me and it turns out to be a consequence of Swift's internal memory model, specifically how it handles weak and unowned references.

In order for this to apply to you, something would have to have a weak or unowned reference to your User object.

If this is the case, when the last strong reference to your object is removed, the object will be deinitialized - anything it references will have its reference count decremented and be deallocated if appropriate, and its deinit() method will be run (as shown by your logs). However, it will not be *deallocated*.

Yes, an object can be deinitalized but not deallocated! The reason for this is that the weak or unowned reference that point at this object must not be allowed to point at deallocated (or worse, re-allocated) memory, because following this pointer would produce "unsafe" behavior. As a result, this section of memory cannot be given up and thus the object is not deallocated.

Two pieces of good news, however. First, only that specific object is being leaked - not any of the objects it references. This means only a tiny bit of memory is being leaked. So it may not be a big deal. Second, for weak references, this behavior is changed in Swift 4 (regrettably unowned references will still have this behavior). It would be interesting to try out your project in Xcode9 beta and see if it still happens.

This is all from asking the same type of question at WWDC. Hope it turns out to applicable!

Comment: Thanks for the insightful reply. In this case I don't think any weak or unowned references are being held. I actually created a completely empty project in the end for this example to replicated the behaviour. All that was in the project was a basically empty `User` class and a `ViewController`. Ended up with these results. 

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not responsible for any of the objects in the graph described, which are the ones retaining the User object, you should not worry about it.

FYI: I have experienced leaks before when including Firebase on an app. It is not your fault, and it should not be leaking a lot of memory.

I agree with @CharlesSrstka , if you are still worried about leaks you can check them too on instruments where it will show you the specific line of code that might be causing the issue.

Comment: add this to your googleservice-info.plist
FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED = NO
it will probably lower the leaks

Answer (score 0):

Was "released user" logged from the object's deinit method? If so, the objects were deinitialized, so whatever references are showing there were not able to keep the object alive. Given that, I'd probably not worry about it, although if you want to be sure, the best thing to do is to fire up Instruments, load the Allocation tool, option-click on the Run button, and check "Record reference counts." This will allow you to see exactly what is retaining and releasing your objects.